# MVC Using relationships Database first

Tags: model-view-controller, relationships

First off I have a list of movies setup from a database working fine on localhost/movies
However I wanted to go a step further so I created an Actors page, I now list all the Actors to ( On their own just their names )
What I want to do is you have for example -

Leonardo DiCaprio (id = 1)
I would like to check the page to see if the id matches him etc ( This is already done as you will see in code below )
Next I would like All his movies he has been in to be shown in another row on the table. As you can see VIA This screenshot 
http://gyazo.com/ae193d80e7a39969116f76ab6568f38e.png
Instead of just the movies he has starred in they all show up, as you can see below I made a relationship between tables Actor & Movie & ActorsMovies, just linking the Ids

I have 3 tables setup like the following:
Movies - 
Id (PK), 
Name

Actor:
Id(PK),
Name

ActorsInMovies:
MovieId(PK),
ActorId(PK)

```
Here is my controller:
public ActionResult Movies( int id )
{
   var model = MoviesViewModel(); //Create our model
   model.PageTitle = = actor.Name + "'s' Movies"; // set page title to actors name
   model.Actorname = actor.Name; // I do this to ensure the name always matches the id
   var items = db.Movies.OrderBy(i => i.Name).AsQueryable(); //Link items to Movies DB    and make it queryable ( as I want to use pagedLists later when its working )
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(actor.Name)) //if name is not null
    {
         items = items.Where( a => a.Id == id );//I already know this is wrong but I dont know what the correct process is I think the theory part behind it I understand, here I need to check the relationships to ensure that the actor matches with the movies I just am unsure how to do it.
    }

        model.MovieList = items.ToList();
        return View(model);         
}
```

and my views is just a normal table with foreach loop in ( im gonna remove the Html so it doesnt get to messy:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.MovieList)
    {               
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Actorname)</td>
            <td>
                <!-- MS:This part populates the table row-->
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: So do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to map many-to-many relationships in MVC and to also limit the number of database queries, is like below. *This also does pagination, since you mentioned the desire.*

**MovieActor schema:** (many-to-many map of Movie and Actor)

- ID (PK)
- ActorID (FK to Actor.ID)
- MovieID (FK to Movie.ID)
- CharacterName

**Controller:**

```
const int Rows = 50; // put this wherever appropriate, or customize and save in Session

/// <summary>
/// This shows all the Movies the given Actor was in.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Actor ID</param>
/// <param name="page">Page of Movies to display, starting at 1</param>
public ActionResult Movies(int id, int page = 1)
{
    // get the actor
    Actor actor = MyDataContext.GetActorByID(id); // one database call

    // get the actor's movies
    List<Movie> movies = MyDataContext
        .GetMoviesByActorID(actor.id) // no database call
        .Skip((page - 1) * Rows)
        .Take(Rows); // one database call

    // build the view model
    // NOTE: could move this into a constructor MoviesViewModel(actor, movies)
    var viewModel = MoviesViewModel
    {
        PageTitle = actor.Name + "'s Movies",
        ActorName = actor.Name,
        Movies = movies
    };

    // show the view
    return View(model);         
}
```

**Model:**

```
public partial class MyDataContext
{
    public Actor GetActorByID(int id)
    {
        return Actors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id)
    }

    public IQueryable<List<Movie>> GetMoviesByActorID(int actorID)
    {
        return Movies.Where(x => x.MovieActor.ActorID == actorID);
    }
}
```

And the view is like any normal `IEnumerable` or `List`.